# How to extend the Tailwind Typography plugin theme with color and color opacity

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to customize the Tailwind Typography plugin, as follows:

```
typography (theme) {
    return {
        DEFAULT: {
            css: {
                'code::before': {
                    content: 'none', // don’t generate the pseudo-element
                    //content: '""', // this is an alternative: generate pseudo element using an empty string
                },
                'code::after': {
                    content: 'none'
                },
                code: {
                    color: theme('colors.slate.700'),
                    fontWeight: "400",
                    backgroundColor: theme('colors.stone.100/30'),
                    borderRadius: theme('borderRadius.DEFAULT'),
                    borderWidth: '1px',
                    paddingLeft: theme('spacing[1.5]'),
                    paddingRight: theme('spacing[1.5]'),
                    paddingTop: theme('spacing[0.5]'),
                    paddingBottom: theme('spacing[0.5]'),
                },
            }
        },
        invert: {
            css: {
                code: {
                    color: theme('colors.slate.100'),
                    backgroundColor: theme('colors.slate.800'),
                    borderColor: theme('colors.slate.600'),
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

How can I apply a color value to backgroundColor - based on one of the built in colors, with with opacity applied? For example `colors.slate.800 / 50` (which doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one. The problem is `theme` function will return HEX value for colors - it simply gets value from resolved configuration in dot notation. So `theme('colors.red.500/300')` is not valid (*at least for now. I think it worth to open PR or [Discussion](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions)*)

All you need to solve the problem is to convert HEX to RGB. There are two Tailwind's ways I know but of course you're free to use any similar approach

First one - convert using Tailwind's `withAlphaVariable` function. It accepts an object with CSS property, color name and variable name.

```js
const withAlphaVariable = require('tailwindcss/lib/util/withAlphaVariable')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      typography: ({theme}) => {

        // This will create CSS-like object
        // you should destruct and override CSS-variable with desired opacity 
        const proseCodeBgColor = withAlphaVariable({
          color: theme('colors.red.500'), // get color from theme config
          property: 'background-color',
          variable: '--tw-my-custom-bg-opacity', // could be any
        })

        return {
          DEFAULT: {
              css: {
                  code: {
                      ...proseCodeBgColor,
                      '--tw-my-custom-bg-opacity': '.3', // opacity
                  },
              }
          },
        }
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography')
  ],
}
```

Second one much simplier - use `@apply` directive. Pass desired Tailwind's utilities as a key and empty object as a value

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      typography: ({theme}) => {
        return {
          DEFAULT: {
              css: {
                  code: {
                      // you may pass as much utilities as you need eg `@apply bg-red-500/30 text-lg font-bold`: {}
                      '@apply bg-red-500/30': {}, 
                  },
              }
          },
        }
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography')
  ],
}
```

Worth to mention you can customize code background as utility `prose-code:bg-blue-500/50`

```html
<div class="prose prose-code:bg-blue-500/50">
  <code>
    npm install tailwindcss
  </code>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/BY2GKM3wdE?file=config)